# Confusion in stack pointer

Tags: java, stack

I am studying the java stack, and am just curious about the pointer in this particular scenario.

When we push an object or a node onto our stack, where does this point:

- at the front of the first node?
- at the back of the first node?

Can anybody help me on this or give some demo link describing a stack pushing and popping the node in the stack? And give me details on where the pointer is pointing any given time.

Comment: First read basic working of the stack data structure and then the java documentation of stack.

Comment: Each class has a javadoc. The javadoc is at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/ (for Java 6)

Comment: @ThreadCreator What links have you looked at on the internet?

Comment: Your question makes little sense. You are confusing `this` reference with something that I can't even identify. You also fail to explain what you mean by the Java stack. Is it some class you are talking about? Anyway, this is not a real question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how a stack works:

You push elements into it like this. The freshly added elements are always "on top" since it is a Last in First Out (LIFO) structure. You can only access the top element:

[image: Stack push]

Then You can pop these elements, but pop always removes the top one, like this:

[image]

If i misunderstood your question, please write a comment, and I will delete this post!

Comment: Stack is a LIFO structure , you can understand it as similar to a stack of books , you can only add / remove the topmost book.

Comment: @bali182, hi but i want to see the pointer.if we pusht the 6 is the pointer of 5 pointing to 6 or the pointer of 6 pointing to the 5.?

Comment: @ThreadCreator - your comment doesn't make sense.  In the example, the things on the stack are numbers.  They don't have pointers pointing to anything else.

Comment: @ThreadCreator Hello! If you store pointers to objects in your stack, then simply imagine the elements in your stack as the numbers in my example (but with the meaning of the address of a memory chunk, where your objects are stored), and your stack as an array with different behavior (basically a stack is wrapper class around an array). The stack will not change where your pointers "point" :)

Comment: @ThreadCreator - In fact, this answer is talking about Stack *data structures*; e.g. as implemented by `java.util.Stack`.

Comment: Hi to all...Okay since i am still learning in stack or a beginner on this can you give me some good link or resources that can help me easily to understand of this.I hope you will help me on this.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> I am studying the java stack, I am just curious about the pointer on this.

Java uses a virtual machine.  The byte code needs to run on a real machine.  This means that in a virtual sense, while it uses a stack to push and pop values off, this is compiled to native code which uses multiple registers (e.g. 8 to 16) as well has a CPU stack which is used selectively (as it is slower)

You can be an experience Java developer without any real idea of Java's stack or how it work virtually or how it translates to native code.  As a beginner, there may be other things which are more useful to know. ;)

Comment: ,i just want to know the pointer for example when 5 is already pushed and then when we push again 6,when we say like this node.next = top..my question on this who is node?is that 5 or 6?and where does the pointer pointing,is it 5 pointing to 6 or 6 pointing to 5?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this question cannot be answered in terms of Java.

The Java Virtual Machine does have conceptual stacks - one for the local frames of a thread, and another for the operands when evaluating expressions.  However, these are *conceptual* stacks, that may or may not be implemented using a native code "stack pointer".  And certainly, any use of native code stacks / stack pointers is an *implementation detail*.

If you want to understand how native stacks / stack pointers work, you are better of reading up on processor architectures, instruction sets, and assembly language programming.  Alternatively, the Wikipedia page on [Call Stacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) gives a ISA neutral description of how they work.